# fixed point math sharpening filter

Tags: c, graphics

Does anyone have a nice fixed point math 1 channel sharpening filter?
Should be done in C using fixed point math.

possible declaration:

```
void sharpen( uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dest, int srcdstpitch, int height );
```

Edited: "Best algorithm realization gets 300 rep bounty". Seems like it's not possible to have a bounty on your own question oO. Nevertheless - I will carefully go through any of winners answers and up 30 answers :).

Comment: "Sharpening filters" are typically very ugly. To perform actual sharpening you need a nonlinear filter that performs some kind of warp on the image. Any linear filter, or any filter that's merely a function of pixel values at fixed locations relative to the target pixel, will give very ugly results. I guess my point is that sharpening is a *vary hard problem* and finding a fixed-point implementation will likely be even harder...

Comment: Your declaration does not compile. What do you mean by `int srcdst pitch`?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself, either implementing, or finding via web search, and if you _then_ have problems, come here and ask specific questions. SO is not a code-sharing site for free.

Comment: @phresnel I did. It has a problem - not fast enough..

Comment: @Ulteriour: Maybe do some research about how to make it fast (start by using a profiler or by reading Agner Fogs optimization guides). Alternatively, try google to get a look at different implementations. Unfortunately, you don't have enough credibility here yet for bounties; and I don't think working around that is proper ...

Comment: @phresnel - could you transfer my rep points to the accept answer author manually?

Comment: @Ulterior: I am afraid I can't, and I don't know if any ordinary member can.

Comment: @Ulterior: re: your flag, if you are confused about something ask a question on [meta].  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is my try. Very simple linear filter that only looks at the nearest neighbors, but it works:

**Edit:** Changed the code to handle the edges of the image separately,
for performance purposes. Made the strength of the sharpening a
parameter to the function.

```
/* Simple Laplacian sharpening. */
void sharpen(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dest, int width, int height, int strength)
{
    int i, j;
    int here, north, south, west, east;
    int sharpening;
    static const int scale = 1024;

    /* Handle interior pixels. */
    for (i = 1; i < height-1; i++) for (j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {

        /* This pixel and it's neighbors. */
        here = src[width*i+j];
        north = src[width*(i-1)+j];
        south = src[width*(i+1)+j];
        west = src[width*i+(j-1)];
        east = src[width*i+(j+1)];

        /* Filter. */
        sharpening = 4 * here - (north + south + west + east);
        here += strength * sharpening / scale;

        /* Store clipped result. */
        dest[width*i+j] = here<0 ? 0 : here>255 ? 255 : here;
    }

    /* Optimization: handle edges separately. */
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        int j_step = (i==0 || i==height-1) ? 1 : width-1;

        for (j = 0; j < width; j += j_step) {

            /* Expand the image by symmetry. */
            north = i==0 ? src[width*(1)+j] : src[width*(i-1)+j];
            south = i==height-1 ? src[width*(height-2)+j] : src[width*(i+1)+j];
            west = j==0 ? src[width*i+(1)] : src[width*i+(j-1)];
            east = j==width-1 ? src[width*i+(width-2)] : src[width*i+(j+1)];

            /* Same as the code for the interior. */
            here = src[width*i+j];
            sharpening = 4 * here - (north + south + west + east);
            here += strength * sharpening / scale;
            dest[width*i+j] = here<0 ? 0 : here>255 ? 255 : here;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it with a PGM image. You can tune the strength of the sharpening
with the last parameter. A strength of 100 is a good starting point.

Comment: If you are after speed, you may want to handle the edges of the image in separate loops. This way the loop for the interior is simplified (`north = src[width*(i-1)+j];` and so on). My tests show this gives a 23% speed gain.

Comment: could you update the code here? I am willing to accept your answer, as I dont expect anything better than that

Comment: OK, I added the optimization and made the strength a parameter of the function.

Comment: PS: Don't worry about the bounty, this is just for fun.

Comment: saw your contributions - IMO you deserve an uplift of 50k here

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the code from [this gimp plug-in](http://www.easysw.com/~mike/gimp/sharpen-1.4.2.tar.gz); doesn't seem that hard.

Comment: And he has not to forget about the license terms, I guess.